# Focusing on RecyclerView selected position when returning to Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity A with a RecyclerView in it, and each view in it has a button that opens a new Activity B. When I go back from B to A, RecyclerView will focus on the first view always.

I want to, when return from B to A by backPress, scroll to the selected view position.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the Position of the clicked item and on resume scroll to that position

```
 int scrollPosition = 0; 
if (linearLayoutManager != null) {
   scrollPosition = inearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
}//to get the position
```

and when restoring use following code

```
if (linearLayoutManager != null) {
  cardRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mScrollPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are starting activity **A** with intent.

I recommend you call `onBackPressed()` when navigating back to activity **A** instead of starting activity **A** as a new `Intent`. If this is the situation.